# Rails 5 cache control doesn't work in heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, cache-control

I am setting up the CDN in my application, and by setting the `cache-control` according to the new standards in Rails 5:

```
config.public_file_server.headers = {
    'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age = 31536000',
    'Expires' => "# {1.year.from_now.to_formatted_s (: rfc822)}"
}
```

But when I'm deploying the application to Heroku, it indicates that I am not using the new standards:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: `config.static_cache_control` is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1.
>       Please use `config.public_file_server.headers = { 'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=604800' }` instead.
>       (called from  at /app/config/application.rb:14)

And when I view the page response headers not being applied `cache-control` to set

[image: Image link]

Comment: Are you sure that you're not setting `config.static_cache_control` elsewhere? Because Heroku is complaining about that, and suggesting to use the settings as you've implemented them.

Comment: @JochemSchulenklopper follow my production.rb file http://pastebin.com/NJb24rkJ, my application not using static_cache_control'm sure of it, I do not really understand why heroku is warning that: /

Comment: Ah, so accidentally your application was setting the `config.static_cache_control`. Not in your config, but through a gem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution on this issue https://github.com/romanbsd/heroku-deflater/issues/26, the problem was with the gem heroku deflater

Comment: Ha, so that gem introduced the `static_cache_control` variable that Heroku was complaining about. Nice catch!

Answer (score 0):

Is that comma between the hash values only missing in this question, or also in your configuration? Try this:

```
config.public_file_server.headers = {
  'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age = 31536000',
  'Expires' => "# {1.year.from_now.to_formatted_s (: rfc822)}"
}
```

Comment: in my production file with this comma, I wrote wrong here I'm sorry, follow my link production http://pastebin.com/NJb24rkJ file, thanks for the help!

Comment: OK, I'm editing your original question (you don't appear to have sufficient karma for that yet) to correct the typo in the text.